# Unable to Create Event Handler for a LinkButton inside a ListView ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, listview, event-handling

This is a weird issue. I have  a List view with 2 Link buttons. "Edit" and "Delete"
Iam able to attach an event handler for the first linkbutton(Update). Code in the event handler executed fine. But If I try to attach a event handler for the second link button(Delete) , I get an error.

My Item Template Looks like this.

```
<ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="MessageLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Item") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:Label ID="URLLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>' />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="EditLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="EditLinkButtonClicked"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'> Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="DeleteLinkButton" runat="server" OnClick="DeleteLinkButtonClicked"
                                CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ItemID") %>'>Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
```

The Event handler declared in the codebehind file are

public void EditLinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    -----
    }

public void DeleteLinkButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    -----
    }
    [Exactly same]

First Item works absolutely fine. But If I attach the second handler, I get the following error
[image]

Am I missing some thing ?
Note - There is no error if I try to attach the 1st event handler to the second link button.[ie EditLinkButtonClicked to DeleteLinkButtonClicked ]
Issue occurs only when I try to attach DeleteLinkButtonClicked to DeleteLinkButton

Any help? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to disable EnableEventValidation for the Page directive and check it.

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" %>
```

If it help then you should to know that:

> This feature reduces the risk of
>   unauthorized or malicious postback
>   requests and callbacks. It is strongly
>   recommended that you do not disable
>   event validation.

regarding to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx
and try to avoid this in the way that was suggested [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223397.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It'd be three things:

- You need to clean, rebuild solution, and reset IIS or close ASP.NET development server (maybe some cache is preventing you to execute the most recent version of the code-behind class).
- Typo. Double-check that...!
- Event handler hasn't the right signature.

Anyway, why don't you use the "Command" event?

You can do OnCommand="Item_Command" and the event handler will have CommandEventArgs which provides you the CommandName and CommandArgument, so you can switch the command name and invoke the logic for editing or deleting respectively.

Read more here:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.commandeventargs_members.aspx

Comment: Thanks Matias.. I checked all your suggestions.But no luck..But the alternate approach you mentioned will definitely help me to move ahead.

Comment: Yeah, this is the approach I'm using everywhere. Commands are better than separate handlers for me. It's ideal for MVC, MVP or anything translating user events into actions.

Answer (score 0):

The same problem occurs in my code. I resolved by using `CausesValidation="false"`

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="YourID" runat="server" **CausesValidation="false"** OnClick="Category_btn_Click1" />
```